# SAPUI5 Expression Binding: true" is of type string, expected boolean for property "blocked"

Tags: sapui5

I have some implementation where I loop over an array of objects and create a new `GenericTile` for each object. I need to set the `blocked` property of the tile dependant of the objects `Count` property.

I tried to use some expression binding for this but I get the following error:

> "true" is of type string, expected boolean for property "blocked" of
>   Element sap.m.GenericTile#exampleTile0

Since my data is not in a model but in an object I try to use some variable in the expression binding. I did not find any example for this case so I am not sure if this can even work or if I need to create a new model (at least the error text sounds for me like the variable is interpreted).

Here is my relevant code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aExampleData.length; i++) {
    var oNewTile = new GenericTile("exampleTile" + i, {
        tileContent: new sap.m.TileContent({
            content: new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
                content: [
                    new sap.m.Title({
                        text: aExampleData[i].Name
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: aExampleData[i].Description
                    }),
                    new sap.m.HBox({
                        items: [
                            new sap.m.Text({
                                text: that.getResourceBundle().getText("count")
                            })
                            new sap.m.Text({
                                text: aExampleData[i].Count
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        }),
        blocked: "{=" + aExampleData[i].Count + "> 0 ? false : true }"
    });

    this.byId(xxx).addItem(oNewTile);
}
```

Can someone give me a hint how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply do `blocked: aExampleData[i].Count <= 0` ? If you want to do it in a more proper "UI5 way", you will probably have to put the data in a JSONModel and bind the parent of the Tiles to it.

Comment: Btw. `.set/getBlocked` are **private APIs** and the property `blocked` is `hidden` (See https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/dd63de234840865b16f621785c1ac8d40ecacf97). I'd suggest to avoid using this property.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I can just use some variable in the loop like:

```
if (aExampleData[i].Count > 0) {
    bBlocked = false;
} else {
    bBlocked = true;
}
```

...and assign it to the blocked property.

However, it would still be interesting to find out if the variable can also be used in the expression binding and how the error can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
blocked: "{=" + aExampleData[i].Count + "> 0 ? false : true }"
```

with

```
blocked: !(aExampleData[i].Count > 0)
```

Using expression syntax here is pointless since there is no binding involved

Answer (score 0):

Well essentially Expression binding was introduced for XML Views

> Expression binding is especially useful in the context of SAPUI5 XML template where XML views with template are prepossessed so that the SAPUI5 controller is a natural place to put custom formatter functions that are not available. [Source](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html)

In JS you can use formatter function for binded values or as Ji aSH mentined just indicating variable condition